# Poincare duality in etale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I am reading etale cohomology and a question about Poincare duality comes to me. Suppose $k$ is a number field and $X/k$ is a smooth variety with dimension $n$ and $Y$ is a possibly singular variety also with dimension $n$, such that $X$ and $Y$ shares a common smooth open subset, i.e. there is a smooth variety $U$ with open embeddings
\begin{equation}
i:U \rightarrow X, ~~j:U \rightarrow Y
\end{equation}
and there exists a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ that restricts to identity one U, i.e.
\begin{equation}
f \circ i=j
\end{equation}
For $\ell$ a prime number, there is an injective morphism between torison sheaves on $Y$,
\begin{equation}
 j_!j^*(\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} 
\end{equation}
from which we get a morphism from $H^n_{et,c}(\overline{U},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) $ to $ H^n_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} )$,
\begin{equation}
H_{et,c}^n(\overline{U},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) \rightarrow H^n_{et}(\overline{Y},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) \xrightarrow{f^*} H^n_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} )
\end{equation}

On the other hand $i$ induces a morphism
\begin{equation}
i^*:H^n_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) \rightarrow H^n_{et}(\overline{U},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} )
\end{equation}
whose Poincare duality also determines a morphism from $H^n_{et,c}(\overline{U},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) $ to $ H^n_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} )$,
\begin{equation}
H^n_{et,c}(\overline{U},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) \rightarrow H^n_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} )
\end{equation}

Are the two morphisms from $H^n_{et,c}(\overline{U},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} ) $ to $ H^n_{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Z}/\ell \mathbb{Z} )$ the same?

More generally, are the two morphisms the same for other Weil cohomology theories when compactly supported cohomology are defined like the etale case?